# Dealing with null when calling JObject.Parse()

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

In the below code, I'm getting an exception due the value with in `JObject.Parse()` resulting in a null, which of course can't be parsed.

```
JObject result = JObject.Parse(responseData["Result"].ToString());
```

To try and work around this I tried the following so that a null check was done before calling parse.

```
var resultString = string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseData["Result"].ToString()) ? "" : responseData["Result"].ToString();
JObject result = JObject.Parse(resultString);
```

This still causes an exception though, I feel like I'm just overlooking something very small here. What can I do to address a possible null value here.

Comment: whats value of responseData["Result"]?

Comment: The value is null

Comment: so u should add a check for null, or use Convert.ToString() not ToString()

Comment: When I do this I still get the error `{"Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0."}` when I pass the result string into the `JObject.parse()` function

Comment: Try to avoid for null

Comment: What type of object is `responseData`?  Is it already a `JToken` or `JObject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JObject result = JObject.Parse(responseData["Result"].ToString());` could be throwing an exception for several reasons:

- If `responseData` itself is null, then trying to access `responseData["Result"]` will throw an exception.
- If `responseData["Result"]` is null (e.g. if there is no key called "Result" present in `responseData`) then trying to access `responseData["Result"].ToString()` will throw an exception.
- If `responseData["Result"].ToString()` is null (or empty), then `JObject.Parse()` will throw because null is not a valid JSON string.

Merely checking `string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseData["Result"].ToString())` is  not good enough to fix it because it only addresses the last of these three cases.  Most likely the exception is being thrown *before* the `ToString()` call, and you are only checking whether the *result* of `ToString()` is null.  By that point it is too late.

When you run into situations like this where you have a complex line of code and it is throwing an exception somewhere within it, it helps to break it down and do null checks at each step.  That way you can easily step through with a debugger and see exactly what is going on.

```
JObject result = null;
if (responseData != null)
{
    object obj = responseData["Result"];
    if (obj != null)
    {
        string str = obj.ToString();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
            result = JObject.Parse(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Having said all that, I want to point out that you seem to be making your code more complex than it needs to be in the first place.  You didn't say in your question what `responseData` is, but based on how you're using it I'm guessing it is a `JObject`.  If that is true, you shouldn't need to convert `responseData["result"]` to string only to then re-parse it back into a `JObject`.  Instead all you need to do is cast it:

```
JObject result = responseData != null ? responseData["Result"] as JObject : null;
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with `JObject.Parse` - I suspect that will handle a null by just returning a null, or empty, JObject.

Most likely is that you;re missing that `responseData["Result"]` is null, and you're trying to call `ToString()` on it. This will cause a `NullReferenceException`

Fix it by checking for null:

```
var resultString = (responseData["Result"] == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseData["Result"].ToString())) 
    ? "" 
    : responseData["Result"].ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still getting the same error though `"Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0."`